# combinatoric question - balls arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can you arrange 200 balls into 40 cells, such that the sum of balls in cells 1-20 is greater (not equal) the sum of balls in cells 21-40?

So, the number of posibilities can be described by:

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{99} {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {k + 20 - 1}  \\
   {20 - 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right)}$$

I was aked not to use $\sum$.
Is there another form to express it?

Comment: Isn't the number of possibilities actually $$\sum_{k=0}^{99}{k+20-1\choose20-1}{200-k+20-1\choose20-1}?$$  The OP's version only counts the number(s) of ways to arrange the $k$ balls in cells 21-40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, the truly correct answer is

$${1\over2}\left({200+40-1\choose40-1}-{100+20-1\choose20-1}^2\right)$$

The ${200+40-1\choose40-1}$ counts the number of ways you can distribute the balls without any restriction.  The $-{100+20-1\choose20-1}^2$ subtracts off the number of arrangements with an equal number in cells 1-20 and 21-40.  The factor $1\over2$ takes care of the symmetry between the two groups of cells.  (For every arrangement with more in one group, there's a corresponding arrangement with more in the other.)  You can simplify this to

$${1\over2}\left({239\choose39}-{119\choose19}^2\right)$$

No doubt *Mathematica* or *Whateverica* can compute the exact value in decimal form; it'll have a lot of digits.

Comment: Why did you square the right expression?

Comment: No, he is left with the cases where one of them wins. But since the conditions are symmetric that means in half of them the set 1-20 wins and in the other half the set 21-40 wins.

Comment: Yeah, I actually understood it and deleted it right away. sorry for that. Can you explain the squared expression please?

Comment: @AndrePoole, you square the ${119\choose19}$ because you have to arrange $100$ balls in cells 1-20 and *another* $100$ balls in cells 21-40.  Each arrangement of $100$ balls in $20$ cells can be done in $119\choose19$ ways, so you multiply the two (equal) numbers together to get the total count.

Comment: Oh right. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the combinatorial identity $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}i=\binom{n+1}{i+1}$

So $\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{k+20-1}{20-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{118}\binom{k}{19}-\sum_{k=0}^{18}\binom{k}{19}=\sum_{k=0}^{118}\binom{k}{19}=\binom{119}{20}$

$=24551856075980529765105$

---

To understand the combinatorial identity assume you want to choose k integers from the set $\{1,2,3...n\}$ Now look at the combinations of $k+1$ elements picked from $\{1,2,3...n,n+1\}$ For a given $m$ how many combinations have m as the largest number? $\binom{m-1}{k}$ Since there are k left to pick and they must be between $m-1$ and $1$. Clearly all combinations of $k+1$ elements have a largest element between $1$ and $m+1$. So the number of combinations of $k+1$ elements picked from $m+1$ elements is $\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m+1}{k}$

Comment: Am I wrong in my comment asking if the OP had written down the correct expression for the number of possibilities?

Comment: I think you are correct, but keep it down, I already got a whole lot of points. I didn't even read the whole question to be honest. I just saw it and thought "blablabla, Oh ok I have to do this".

Comment: Mum'sthe word. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$$24551856075980529765105$$
by [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%20=%200%29%5E%2899%29%20C%28k%2b19,19%29). This is one of the expressions without using $\sum$.

Comment: don't know why downvote?

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a downvote. +1 for a good answer

Comment: @Shaktal: Thanks. OP is the person who decides this is an appropriate answer. In addition to this, OP never says this is not an appropriate answer.