# The identity with sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Is this formula true?

$$
\sum_{m=k}^n {m \choose k}={n+1 \choose k+1}
$$

If yes how to prove it?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Try induction on $n$

Comment: You can also do a combinatorial proof by counting the number of subsets of $\{0,\dots,n\}$ which have $k+1$ elements.  In the first sum, $m$ is the largest element of the subset.

Comment: I strongly believe this is a duplicate, now looking for it.

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619940/sum-of-binomial-coefficients?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

**Combinatorial proof**

Let $A=\{0,\cdots,n\}$.  This set has $n+1$ elements, so $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\k+1\end{pmatrix}$ counts the number of subsets of size $k+1$.

On the other hand, for any subset of size $k+1$, let $m$ be its largest element.  It is certainly true that $k\leq m\leq n$.  Since $\begin{pmatrix}m\\k\end{pmatrix}$ is the number of subsets of $\{0,\cdots,m-1\}$ with $k$ elements, it is also the number of subsets of $\{0,\cdots,n\}$ with $k+1$ elements and $m$ as the largest element.

These two counts count the same thing, and, therefore, are equal.

Answer (score 1):

there is also a straightforward inductive proof based on
$$
\sum_{m=k}^{n+1} {m \choose k}= \sum_{m=k}^n {m \choose k}+{n+1 \choose k} = {n+1 \choose k+1}+{n+1 \choose k}={n+2 \choose k+1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that when we introduce the integral representation
$${m\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^m}{z^{k+1}}\; dz$$

we get for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\sum_{m=k}^n
\frac{(1+z)^m}{z^{k+1}}\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}
\sum_{m=k}^n
(1+z)^m \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}
\frac{(1+z)^{n+1}-(1+z)^k}{1+z-1} \;dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+2}}
\left((1+z)^{n+1}-(1+z)^k\right) \; dz.$$

This has two pieces, the first of which is
$${n+1\choose k+1}$$
and the second, which is zero,
thus concluding the proof.

This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194647/) has another computation in the same spirit.